# Free fall and gravitational waves

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, free-fall, equivalence-principle, binary-stars

If you take the Earth-Moon system, from what I understand, the Moon for instance is in free fall towards the Earth-Moon center of mass. However Einstein's equivalence principle says that a body in free fall is in inertial motion. Then why does the Moon (and any binary system in general) emit gravitational waves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However Einstein's equivalence principle says that a body in free fall is in inertial motion.

This holds in the limit of a small body (a "test mass."). It is not true except in that limit, and for exactly the reason you've expressed.

Comment: Small as in small radius or small mass? If the former then gravitational radiation is a function of the radii of two bodies?

Comment: @Opt: It's complicated, but basically both, and you also need an energy condition. You need a small mass so that radiation is negligible. You need a small radius because otherwise it's not clear what is meant by the world-line. For a simplified pedagogical discussion, see sec. 8.1.3 of my GR book, which is free online at http://www.lightandmatter.com/genrel/ .